# libmpi_cxx.so.40: cannot open shared object file

Tags: linux, mpi, conda, openmpi

Upon running a command that requires mpi, it fails with

```
error while loading shared libraries: libmpi_cxx.so.40: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm running it in a conda environment `pytorch_p36`.
However, I checked that `libmpi_cxx.so.40` is present in that same conda environment.
Command

```
locate libmpi_cxx
```

Output

```
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/libmpi_cxx.so
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/libmpi_cxx.so.40
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36/lib/libmpi_cxx.so.40.20.1
```

Is there some issue with `PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?
If so what? How can I make sure anaconda environment libs are picked up by the 2 environment vars?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX/lib [[rest of your command, e.g. python foo.py]]
```

Comment: Not sure if $CONDA_PREFIX is /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_p36 in his case, but if it is, this should work. If it doesn't, try appending $CONDA_PREFIX/lib in front of LD_LIBRARY_PATH: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu

```
sudo apt install libopenmpi3
```

Haha, I googled the name of the file and found this:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/focal/amd64/libopenmpi3/filelist

After installing, seemed to work!  I was using a special build of pytorch that didn't have it included.